# SQL Server Management Studio tool to check errors in stored procedures and views

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, view, ssms

I have made some changes in the schema of some tables in SQL Server and rename some columns, is there a way to save all changes I made in separate file to be applied to production database?

Also is there a way to discover the errors that happen in stored procedures and views because of these changes?

Comment: This is when database projects work well, as the build for the database will fail on the invalid objects.

Comment: yes but it is very hard to do this via code, especially when you have more than 100 Stored procedure, and when the classes is build by other developers that will be affected by your change, I am asking if there is something that can show the errors and allow me to change it from SSMS directly ?

Comment: Database projects (SSDT) make the task easier not harder. All your object definitions would be in source control in a database project. It makes no difference that there are more than 100 of them. The database changes would then be applied by publishing the database project (dacpac) - ideally by devops pipelines that validate that there are no errors first. And further ideally after ensuring that all tSQLt tests pass

Comment: I've struggled with this myself. I started a hugh DB application and I routinely make changes to the DB schema. Then, how do I roll that out to other distributors using my application? I wish I started the app as a code-first Entity Framework application but I didn't know of such things when I started. Trying to create DB upgrade scripts manually was a pain, which I abandoned. Now, I publish an upgraded, empty DB copy and created a migration script to pull all the data from the old DB version into the upgraded DB. Then, drop the old DB. Not ideal, but it works for my limited use case.

Comment: Or, use a (paid) DB upgrade/migration tool, there are a few good ones. It will take your old DB as a base, then analyse the upgraded DB and create change scripts. Or as mentioned above, gain a better understanding or tools freely available. I didn't know about Database Projects so I'll have to read up on them.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this 2 ways:

1. The manual way, using a large SQL script created from a number of smaller scripts from SQL Server Management Studio or created by myself.  It can be tricky but not so difficult once you've created a few of them.
2. The automatic way - using RedGate SQL Compare.  Much easier if you have access to it.

When using both methods I would use  require a Pre-Prod database (a copy of Production) for testing.